# Vuetify - Change color of each date for calendar-monthly component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to display attendance status of employee using calendar-monthly component.

```
<v-calendar type="month" :value="###">
          <template v-slot:day="{ present, past, date }">
            <v-row no-gutters style="height:2.5rem">
              <template v-if="events[date]">
                <v-col class="text-center">
                  <v-chip
                    label
                    dark
                    @click="###"
                    :title="###"
                    :color="###"
                    v-for="###"
                    :key="i"
                  >{{###}}</v-chip>
                </v-col>
              </template>
            </v-row>
          </template>
        </v-calendar>
```

Each slot contains chips to represent another data. So, to display attendance status(*Present or Absent*) of employee I want to change color of date. Is there a way to do that, or any other suggestion on how I can implement this feature would be appreciated.